# Lower bound for $(x^c-1)^{1/c}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, approximation

I have been trying to find a lower bound for $x>1$, $c>0$:

$$
\Large(x^c-1)^{1/c}
$$

My strategy is to find a lower bound for $(x^c-1)^{1/c}$ which can hopefully get rid of some of the $c$ powers. My guess is it should be greater than something along the lines of $x-\frac{1}{x^{c-1}}$.

If $c>1$ I can use convexity of $x^{1/c}$ I can write $(x-1)^{1/c}\ge x^{1/c}-\frac{1}{c}(x-1)^{1/c-1}$, however while it allows me cancel out one pair of $c$ and $\frac{1}{c}$ it just creates a new one.

Do you have any ideas what sort of inequalities I might benefit from having a look at?

Comment: How about $(x^c-1)^{1/c}\ge (x^c)^{1/c}=x$ assuming $x$ and $c$ are positive, you didn't specify conditions on them.

Comment: Yes, I got the same idea. Taking in account he wrote $\log(x)$ we can assume that $x$ is positive.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the inner $\log$. Just removing the minus doesn't give a sufficiently tight bound. (Everything just becomes 1)

Comment: I can also use the binomial theorem to write $(x^c-1)^{1/c}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {1/c \choose k}(-1)^kx^{1-kc}=x-\frac{1}{c}x^{1-c}-\frac{c-1}{2c^2}x^{1-2c}-\dots$, but since all the terms are negative, truncating this sequence will only give me an upper bound... (well, unless $c<1$, I guess)

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive about your restrictions on $c$? So you mean $c \geq C > 0$?

Comment: $c>0$, but it can be smaller than 1. If necessary I would also be interested in $c\ge C>0$ for some small $C$.

Comment: So then you must have some restriction on $x$, yes? There are problems when $x < 1$ if $c$ is positive.

Comment: You are right. $x$ can be considered 'large enough'.

Comment: Maybe a bound will have to consider separate cases for $c$ greater or less than $1$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this myself. There are two bounds, depending on $c$ being greater than, or less than 1:

$$(x^c-1)^\frac{1}{c} \ge \begin{cases}
   x\left(1-\frac{1}{cx^c}\right) & \text{if } 0 < c \le 1 \\
   x\left(1-\frac{1}{c(x^c-1)}\right) & \text{if } 0 < c
  \end{cases}$$

This first bound follows from convexity, and the second one follows from the binomial theorem like this:

$$
\begin{align}
(x^c-1)^\frac{1}{c} &= \sum_k{1/c\choose k}(-1)^k(x^c)^{1/c-k}\\
&=x-\frac{1}{c}x^{1-c}\left(1+\frac{1-1/c}{2!}x^{-c}+\frac{(1-1/c)(2-1/c)}{3!}x^{-2c}+\dots\right)\\
&\ge x-\frac{1}{c}x^{1-c}\left(1+x^{-c}+x^{-2c}+\dots\right)\\
&= x-\frac{1}{c}x^{1-c}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^c-1}\right)\\
&= x\left(1-\frac{1}{c(x^c-1)}\right)
\end{align}$$

Experimentally, the bound is a lot better for large $c$'s than small ones. However since the second one is strictly smaller than the first one, it might be simpler to just always use that one.

If we underestimate the binomial sum more tightly as $x-\frac{1}{c}x^{1-c}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}x^{-c}+\frac{1}{3}x^{-2c}+\dots\right)$ we get the bound $\ge x\left(1+\frac{\log(1-x^{-c})}{c}\right)\ge x\left(1-\frac{1}{c(x^c-1)}\right)$ which is the same as before.

As a corollary this gives
$$1+\frac{\log2}{c(\log_2x)^{c-1}}\le\frac{x}{2^{(\log_2x)^c-1)^{1/c}}} \le 1+\frac{\log2}{(c-\epsilon)(\log_2x)^{c-1}}$$ for $0<\epsilon<c\neq1$ and $x$ large enough, which was the problem I was interested in originally.

Comment: I think it would be better to write it as $(x^c-1)^\frac{1}{c} \ge \begin{cases}
   x\left(1-\frac{1}{cx^c}\right) & \text{if } 0 < c \le 1 \\
   x\left(1-\frac{1}{c(x^c-1)}\right) & \text{if } 1 < c
  \end{cases}$. In this form, it shows in a better way that $(x^c-1)^{\frac{1}{c}}$ behaves more like $x$ as $x\to\infty$ since clearly $(x^c-1)^{\frac{1}{c}}\leq x$.